# How do I encrypt a message and then I decryot it on another device with javax.crypto.cipher using AES

Tags: java, encryption

I have a problem with my code. I want to encrypt a message using a key made from passphrase. Then I want to send it (or use it somewhere, whatever) in String form (the encrypted one), and after that I want to decrypt it only by knowing the passphrase.

I wrote the code below, but I receive either `IllegalBlockSizeException` or `BadPaddingException`. I thought that badding would be took care by padding.

Here is my code:

**Constructor and initialization:**

```
public class AES_Cipher {

    private String keyString;
    private byte[] byteKey;
    private SecretKey key;
    Cipher c;

    public AES_Cipher(String keyString){
        this.keyString = keyString.toString();
    }

    public void init() throws InitializtionFailedException{
        try{
            c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            byteKey = keyString.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byteKey = sha.digest(byteKey);
            byteKey = Arrays.copyOf(byteKey, 16);
            key = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "AES");

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            throw new InitializtionFailedException();
        }
}
```

**Encrypt:**

```
public String encrypt(String text) throws EncryptionException{
    try{
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] tmp = c.doFinal( text.getBytes("UTF-8")); 

            return new String(tmp, "UTF-8");
        }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
            throw new EncryptionException();
        }
}
```

**Decrypt:**

```
public String decrypt(String text) throws DecryptionException{
        try{

        //byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(text);
        // tried too use it but with poor outcome
        //c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] tmp1 = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        //byte[] tmp = c.doFinal("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".getBytes());
        //this returns BadPaddingException
        byte[] tmp = c.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        return new String(tmp, "UTF-8");

    }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
    throw new DecryptionException();
    }
}
```

Of course there are some more exceptions.

Also, I would like to later use this code on android, and It doesn't need to be `AES` if there is some other Ciphers that are maybe less effective but less troublesome. But not simple `XOR` if that's not too much too ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with AES. This would happen with every modern cipher. The issue is `new String(tmp, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalBlockSizeException when trying to encrypt and decrypt a string with AES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383736/illegalblocksizeexception-when-trying-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-with-aes)

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Could you explain? How should I parse the String if not this way? And i thought if I use the same charset all the time it should work.

Comment: Ok. So I menaged to handle it using BASE64Encoder and BASE64Decoder. Thanks for pointing me to the error :).Now I try to use it on android but I can't since there is no BASE64Encoder or Decoder. It only has BASE64 but it requires byte[] already, so it forces me to use String(tmp, "UTF-8") in order to convert encrypted byte array to String so I can send it further. And I don't see any exceptions in the logcat thus I am kind of blind. All I know it crashes on doFinal. Any thoughts that could help me?

Comment: There's the `Base64#encodeToString()`, which should be equivalent to `new String(Base64.encode(tmp), "UTF-8")`. Base64 encoded characters are all printable and compatible with ASCII.

Comment: Ok. I'm ussing it but decryption doesn't seem to work...
My code:
Encryption:
`c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
            byte[] tmp = c.doFinal(textByte);
            String return1 = Base64.encodeToString(tmp, Base64.DEFAULT);`

and decryption:

`.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] textByte = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] tmp = c.doFinal(textByte);

            return new String(tmp, "UTF-8"); //Base64.encodeToString(tmp, Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: Well, you're using `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` twice. Please don't post extensive code into the comments. [edit] your question to include additional code.

Comment: OK. Sorry for that. It seems to work, but I'll do some additional tests. Anyway I want to thank you very much. You're a genius, mate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Seems to work now thanks to Artjom B.

Constructor and inicialization:
public class AES_Cipher {

```
private String keyString;
private byte[] byteKey;
private SecretKey key;
Cipher c;

public AES_Cipher(String keyString){
    this.keyString = keyString.toString();
}

public void init() throws InitializtionFailedException{
    try{
        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        byteKey = keyString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byteKey = sha.digest(byteKey);
        byteKey = Arrays.copyOf(byteKey, 16);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "AES");

    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        throw new InitializtionFailedException();
    }
 }
```

Encryption:

```
 public String encrypt(String text) throws EncryptionException{
    try{
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
        byte[] tmp = c.doFinal(textByte);

        String return1 = Base64.encodeToString(tmp, Base64.DEFAULT);


        return return1;
}   // of course there is some exceptions catched down there
```

Decryption:

```
public String decrypt(String text) throws DecryptionException{
    try{

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] textByte = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);

        byte[] tmp = c.doFinal(textByte);

        return new String(tmp, "UTF-8");

    }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        Log.d("Exception", "IllegalBlockSizeException");
        throw new DecryptionException();

    }  // wrote DecryptionException myself. 
       // also there is more Exceptions below
}
```