# wrong AES cipher in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I try to use AES in Java. I found a code snippet but output is wrong. There is a lot of `EF BF BD` in output. I could not find what is wrong with my code ?

```
public class AES
{
static String encryptionKey = "48C3B4286FF421A4A328E68AD9E542A4";
    static String clearText = "00000000000000000000000000000000";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        encr();
    }

    public static String toHexString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", ba[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void encr() throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException
    {
        //Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        byte[] clearTextBytes = clearText.getBytes("UTF8");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearTextBytes);

        System.out.print("enc1:  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherBytes.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(cipherBytes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        String cipherText = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8");
        System.out.println("enc2: " + cipherText);

        System.out.println("enc3: " + toHexString(cipherText.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

output is :

```
enc1:  51 72 -122 -57 -109 127 57 85 116 63 -89 -35 55 -72 37 -96 51 72 -122 -57 -109 127 57 85 116 63 -89 -35 55 -72 37 -96 -82 103 -117 -60 -102 -91 -51 55 -53 23 33 -82 -70 -14 74 41 
enc2: 3H�Ǔ9Ut?��7�%�3H�Ǔ9Ut?��7�%��g�Ě��7�!���
enc3: 33 48 EF BF BD C7 93 7F 39 55 74 3F EF BF BD EF BF BD 37 EF BF BD 25 EF BF BD 33 48 EF BF BD C7 93 7F 39 55 74 3F EF BF BD EF BF BD 37 EF BF BD 25 EF BF BD EF BF BD 67 EF BF BD C4 9A EF BF BD EF BF BD 37 EF BF BD 17 21 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD
```

but it should be

```
33  48  86  c7  93  7f  39  55  74  3f  a7  dd  37  b8  25  a0
```

Comment: enc1 and enc2 outputs are correct, right ? Only issue seems to be in enc2 : toHexString function's sysout statement, right ?

Comment: What do you expect new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8"); to return when cipherBytes contains AES encrypted data and not UTF-8 encoded characters?

Comment: It looks to me that you already have everything that you need. You just have to put it together: `toHexString(cipherBytes)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalBlockSizeException when trying to encrypt and decrypt a string with AES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383736/illegalblocksizeexception-when-trying-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-with-aes)

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks. `toHexString(cipherBytes)` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you print `toHexString(cipherText.getBytes("UTF-8"))`, the result is

> 33 48 86 C7 93 7F 39 55 74 3F A7 DD 37 B8 25 A0 33 48 86 C7 93 7F 39 55 74
>    3F A7 DD 37 B8 25 A0 AE 67 8B C4 9A A5 CD 37 CB 17 21 AE BA F2 4A 29

When you convert to `byte[]` to `String`, java drop invalid data base on the charset.