# InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long

Tags: java, spring-boot, cryptography

I am in the process of getting a Spring Boot (Java) application deployed on a Production environment. It works properly in our QA environment, however in our Production environment, the application goes into an endless loop of starting, failing and then restarting.

We get this error in our std.out before it attempts to restart again:

```
Caused by: com.acme.security.encryptionservice.acmeSecurityException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long
        at com.acme.security.encryptionservice.EncryptionService.decrypt(EncryptionService.java:84)
        at com.acme.abc.commons.utils.DecryptUtil.decrypt(DecryptUtil.java:38)
        at com.acme.abc.report.sender.config.SftpConfig.orgIdSessionFactory(SftpConfig.java:116)
        at com.acme.abc.report.sender.config.SftpConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fff27ac.CGLIB$orgIdSessionFactory$1(<generated>)
        at com.acme.abc.report.sender.config.SftpConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fff27ac$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$868ea80c.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at com.acme.abc.report.sender.config.SftpConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fff27ac.orgIdSessionFactory(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 57 more Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:526)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:346)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:863)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java)
```

So here's my question - this code works fine in QA. What should I be looking at in the Production environment to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running this inside a Tomcat container? If so, I would suggest that you check the $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml settings and compare them between your QA and Prod environments. You also may have different Cipher Suites installed between your environments.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729834/need-solution-for-wrong-iv-length-in-aes seems iv parameter length is defined wrong.